# .Statuses folder doesnt open on every device

Tags: whatsapp

```
private fun getWhatsAppStatusesAboveQ() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
            // Attempt to directly open the .Statuses directory
            val uriToLoad = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses")
            // Fallback URI to the WhatsApp media directory
            val fallbackUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia")
            try {
                putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                // If the system doesn't accept the URI, fallback to the parent directory
                putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, fallbackUri)
            }
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
}
```

Here is my code, that I did in MainActivity.kt. And through method channel, it sends data to the dart file as it is a flutter app.

But, this function doesn't open the statuses folder for every device, on most devices the folder before 'Android' is opened.

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.DocumentsContract
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.video.editor.video.trimmer.status.upload.whatsappstatus/status"
    private var result: MethodChannel.Result? = null
    private val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10002 // Any number you want
    private val REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE = 10001
    private val PREFS_FILE_NAME = "AppPreferences"
    private val SAVED_URI_KEY = "WhatsAppStatusUri"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            this.result = result
            when (call.method) {
                "getWhatsAppStatus" -> {
                    checkWhatsAppPermission()
                }
                else -> {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkWhatsAppPermission() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedUriString = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_URI_KEY, null)

        if (savedUriString != null) {
            val savedUri = Uri.parse(savedUriString)
            getWhatsAppStatuses(savedUri)
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                getWhatsAppStatusesAboveQ()
            } else {
                getWhatsAppStatusesBelowQ()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getWhatsAppStatusesAboveQ() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
            // Attempt to directly open the .Statuses directory
            val uriToLoad = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses")
            // Fallback URI to the WhatsApp media directory
            val fallbackUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia")
            try {
                putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                // If the system doesn't accept the URI, fallback to the parent directory
                putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, fallbackUri)
            }
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    }

    private fun getWhatsAppStatusesBelowQ() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        } else {
            val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses"
            val files = getFilesFromPath(path)
            result?.success(files)
        }
    }

    private fun getFilesFromPath(path: String): List<String> {
        val directory = File(path)
        val files = directory.listFiles()
        return files?.mapNotNull { it.absolutePath } ?: emptyList()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS -> {
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    getWhatsAppStatusesBelowQ()
                } else {
                    result?.error("PERMISSION_DENIED", "Permission denied by the user", null)
                }
            }
            else -> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = data?.data
            if (uri != null) {
                val takeFlags: Int = data.flags and
                        (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)

                val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SAVED_URI_KEY, uri.toString()).apply()

                getWhatsAppStatuses(uri)
            } else {
                result?.error("CANCELED", "No data returned from activity", null)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getWhatsAppStatuses(uri: Uri) {
        val documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri)
        val filePathsList = documentFile?.listFiles()?.mapNotNull {
            if (it.name?.endsWith(".jpg") == true || it.name?.endsWith(".mp4") == true) {
                val tempFile = File(cacheDir, it.name!!)
                copyContentUriToFile(it.uri, tempFile)
                tempFile.absolutePath
            } else {
                null
            }
        } ?: emptyList()
        result?.success(filePathsList)
    }

    private fun copyContentUriToFile(uri: Uri, file: File) {
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

            inputStream?.use { input ->
                outputStream.use { output ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // buffer size
                    while (true) {
                        val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
                        if (byteCount < 0) break
                        output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
                    }
                    output.flush()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to copy URI content.", e)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the complete code.

For permissions, I want the `.Statuses` folder to be opened directly. But on most devices it doesn't open the correct path.